# How to get HWID

Tags: c++, windows, hwid

I am trying to get `HWID` through the `hwProfileInfo` class, but it returns me that i can't convert `WCHAR` [39] to String.

```
string getHWID(){
  string hardware_guid

  HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;
  GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo);
  hardware_guid = hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid;

  return hardware_guid;
}
```

Than i tried this way, but it returns me just "{"

```
hardware_guid = (char*)hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid;
```

I know there are some more ways in Google, but i didn't find any working variants. May be there are some people, who can say the 100% method?

Comment: Do you realize what is the difference between `WCHAR [39]` and `string`?

Comment: You need to use `std::wstring`.

Comment: I'm assuming that `string` means `std::string`. `std::string` uses `char`s, while `WCHAR` is a Windows alias for `wchar_t`. You have a couple choices: (1) change `string` to `wstring`, or (2) convert the Unicode-encoded `WCHAR[39]` to a `std::string`. If you're using C++11 or later, you may want to look at `std::wstring_convert` ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert ). Since you're on Windows, you can use `WideCharToMultiByte` ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx ) but that can be tricky.

Comment: The above code doesn't even compile due to a missing semi-colon.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This is the answer to my question.

```
string getHWID(){  
  HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;
  GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo);
  wstring hwidWString = hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid;  
  string hwid(hwidWString.begin(), hwidWString.end());

  return hwid;
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely *not* the answer to your question. A `std::wstring` object cannot be converted into a `std::string` object using iterators. They are entirely different types. The iterators should not even be compatible.

Comment: @Cody Gray lol but anyway it works and it gives me hwid that i want

Comment: like this {e29ac6c0-7037-11de-816d-806e6f6e6963}

Comment: "It works on my computer, so it must be correct" - not really. Now ship it and see how much it breaks on your consumers' computers!

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods:
1st You can use std::wstring, which uses wchar_t, instead of std::string, which uses char.
2nd You can use GetCurrentHwProfileA instead of GetCurrentHwProfileW, which will be defined as GetCurrentHwProfile if UNICODE is defined.